# Can I balance load between two instances of bitcoin daemon by switching RPC request?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, balance

The question is pretty simple.

I have two instances of bitcoin daemon. When I'm running my pool with parallel RPC requests to each instance it calls daemons too often and daemons queue of RPC calls exceeding. I want to balance calls between instances.

**The main question: can I get job from `DAEMON 1` pass it to mining devices but submit share to `DAEMON 2`?**

Do jobs stateless or if I got job from the `daemon 1` I must submit PoW to that daemon too?

If not, can you explain why? And did you know how to properly load balance between bitcoin instances?